# Multiple Controller As Syntax with One Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have Routes and Controllers like below

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/data/user.html',
        controller : 'UserController as usr'
    })
    .when('/add-schema', {
        templateUrl : '/data/group.html',
        controller : 'GroupController as grp'
   })

}])

/*Note That I dont want to use $scope*/

.controller('UserController', function($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.total_rows = 90;
})
.controller('GroupController', function($http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.total_rows = 60;
});
```

And I want to use only one pagination Directive for all pages , smth like this

```
.directive('datasPagination', function() {

  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<ul class="pagination"><li>{{total_rows}}</li></ul>'
  }

});
```

How to get the {{total_rows}} inside my Directive given that I use Controller As Syntax with different aliases and I dont use $scope ? . Above, I use "usr" and "grp" as Alias

Regards

Comment: have you tried to use an isolated scope and pass the value through an attribute?

Otherwise you have to use a scope...

Comment: in your directive add require: 'ngController' and in link function fourth argument will give you controller instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to isolate the directive scope, this is useful when you want to build a reusable component...

```js
APP.directive('datasPagination', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      rows: "="
    },
    template: '<ul class="pagination"><li>{{rows}}</li></ul>'
  }

});
```

```html
<!-- where alias is the alias defined in controllerAs syntax -->
<data-pagination rows="alias.total_rows" />
```

### [further reading here](https://thinkster.io/egghead/understanding-isolate-scope)

Comment: What if I use different aliases for each Controller ? 

Above, I use "usr" and "grp" as Alias

Comment: yeah, but, you share the variables across the controller scop to the isolated scope, so, don't care how it is named...
Simply use one time usr.total_rows and then grp.total_rows... 
In your directive this data is always called rows

Comment: sorry...one more thing....what about ng-aclick action inside the directive ? 

smth like : ng-click="getDataPagination(page)"

Comment: When you use an isolated-scope the scope of the controller isn't shared with the directive, so, if this function is defined outside the isolated scope you cannot access to it... 
You can share it using attributes, as I did for the rows variable...